# tmux: can't bind C-{ without prefix

Tags: tmux, macos

I want to jump between windows with the same shortcuts as in web browser.

So I tried

```
bind-key -n "C-{" previous-window
bind-key -n "C-}" next-window
```

and

```
bind-key -n "C-S-[" previous-window
bind-key -n "C-S-]" next-window
```

It is not working.

I'm using macos, kitty and zsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `^{` character.

There are 32 ^X control characters for bytes 0 to 0x1f: `^@`, `^A`..`^Z`, `^[`, `^\` , `^]`, `^^`, `^_`. Also `^?` which is byte 0x7f, the last character in the ASCII set.

Note that terminals send `^I` on both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `^[` on both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd>, `^M` on both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Upon <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, some send `^H` (BS) some `^?` (DEL). Some send `^@` (NUL) on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, etc. IOW, characters send upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + some key are control characters (characters that have a control function, like `^M` which is carriage-return which returns the teletypewriter's carriage to the start position), of which there is only a limited set in ASCII (33 in total).

On my British PC keyboard `{` is on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and with my terminal emulator (xterm) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> sends `^[` like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> do. AFAICT, kitty sends nothing upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

You could always configure it so it sends some particular character or sequence of characters upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (or the equivalent on your keyboard), and then bind *that* to something in your tmux configuration.

For instance, with:

```
map ctrl+shift+[ send_text all \x1b[23~
map ctrl+shift+] send_text all \x1b[24~
```

In your `~/.kitty/kitty.conf`, `kitty` would send the same sequences as it's know to send for the <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> keys (that `\x1b` here being `^[` aka ESC).

And you could bind that in the tmux configuration with:

```
bind-key -n "F11" previous-window
bind-key -n "F12" next-window
```